# SharePoint designer 2013 Directory

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I have installed SP Designer 2013. The directory I have is `C:\Program files\common files\Microsoft shared\Web server extension\15\BIN`.

I am looking for `template\layout` also, why can't I see them,

Comment: do you have sharepoint install on that machine? what u trying to do?

Comment: Becouse SharePoint Designer is used to check and work with the internal structure of a site, Instead "template\layouts" is a phisical path and it's part of the installation of SharePoint. That folder is located at "[drive]:\program Files\common files\microsoft shared\web server extension\15". If u dont have sharepoint installed on that machine you will never have access to that folder.

Comment: yes I have it.. I am trying to create a workflow.. I receive error message "site configured disallow editing in sharepoint designer 2013"

Comment: That means you can't, your admins have disabled designer access on that site.

Comment: I googled the error..resolution needs \template folder

Comment: @EricAlexander how to fix this?

Comment: I have sharepoint designer installed what elso should I install? @Marco

Comment: talk with your IT folks or your site collection administrator, SPD has explicitly been disabled

Comment: thanks@EricAlexander  just to make sure I have installed sharepoint designer only .. do I need to download something else?

Comment: Ruby, do what @EricAlexander is telling you. Talk to your admins. You don't need to do anything else, just have them re-enable SPD if they're willing to do so and have at least Designer rights on the Site Collection you will be connecting to.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the above useful conversation , I noticed that you got the following issue

> site configured disallow editing in SharePoint designer 2013.

[image]

**This error occurs if**

- The web application has been configured to disallow site editing via SharePoint Designer.
- In a case of you are using a project site template, the Web design features are disabled in ONET.XML file By default.

To overcome this issue ask your site administrator to follow the mentioned steps at [This website has been configured to disallow editing with SharePoint Designer](https://blog.devoworx.net/2014/11/14/this-web-site-has-been-configured-to-disallow-editing-with-sharepoint-designer/) to can

- Enable SharePoint designer for this web application

  > in Central Administration > Application Management > Manage web application > from the above ribbon > Select General Settings > SharePoint Setting. > Enable.
- Enable the Web design features in ONET.XML if required (For PWA Template).

Answer (score 0):

I got this error of "site configured disallow editing in SharePoint designer...
" when I tried to open a SharePoint 2013 website using SharePoint Designer 2007. Switched to SharePoint Designer 2013, then it works!